# Javascript remove array objects with duplicate properties while keeping the latest version

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates, underscore.js

I'm trying to remove older version of the same object with duplicate IDs but different properties.

My array containing history of modifications to objects and it looks something like this:

```
[

  {
    id:"1",
    status:"foo",
    day: "01/01/1111"
  },
  {
    id:"2",
    status:"foo",
    day: "01/01/1111"
  },
  {
    id:"1",
    status:"bar",
    day: "02/01/1111"
  },

]
```

I'd like to filter this array so there are no object with duplicate id. However the latest version is kept. In this case, with id one. The version with `status:'bar'` is kept.

How would I go about doing this? I'm using `underscore.js` in other part of the project. And I know that it has _.uniq. But i'm not sure how to use it so that it gives me the latest version.

By the way, I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062546/remove-objects-with-a-duplicate-property-from-a-javascript-array), which is very similar to what I'm asking. But that was from 5 years ago, so I was wondering if there's a more modern way of doing htings.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you are after?

```
function updateList(a_list) {

    var seen = {};

    for (var entry in a_list) {
        var id = a_list[entry]["id"];

        if (seen.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
            var current_newest_date = new Date(seen[id]["day"]).getTime();
            var check_newest_date = new Date(a_list[entry]["day"]).getTime();

            if (current_newest_date < check_newest_date) {
                 seen[id] = a_list[entry];
            }

        } else {
            seen[id] = a_list[entry];
        }
    }

    var updated = [];
    for (var newest in seen) {
        updated.push(seen[newest]);
    } 
    return updated;
}
```

This assumes that your date is in Month/Day/Year Format.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

Sort your array by date descending

```
data.sort(function(a,b) {
    if ( new Date(a.day) > new Date(b.day) )
        return -1;
    if ( new Date(a.day)< new Date(b.day))
        return 1;
    return 0;
} );
```

After this you can remove the duplicate objects

```
var temp = {};
for(var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++ ){
    var obj = data[i];
    if(temp[obj.id] >= 0){
        data.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
    }
    temp[obj.id] = i;
}
console.log(data)
```

It works and simple too.. :)

Answer (score 0):

sort the array by id and filter resulting array by day

```
function Filter(arrObjs){

  function sortId(a, b){
    return a.id - b.id;
  }

  var y = arrObjs.sort(sortId);

  var result = [];

  var max = y[0].day;
  for(var i = 1; i < y.length; i++){

    if(y[i -1].id == y[i].id){
        if(y[i].day > max){
           max = y[i].day;
        }
    }
    else{
        result.push(y[i -1]);
        max = y[i].day;
        if(i + 1 === y.length)
           result.push(y[i]);
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any filters and sorts, a totally high performance solution with O(n) (single pass). Note that in some cases it might result a sparse array since we are using the ids as indices.

```js
var data = [{id:"1",status:"foo",day: "01/01/1111"},{id:"2",status:"foo",day: "01/01/1111"},{id:"1",status:"bar",day: "02/01/1111"},],
 reduced = data.reduce((p,c) => {var d1 = !!p[c.id] && new Date(p[c.id].day),
                                     d2 = new Date(c.day);
                                 (!d1 || d1 < d2) && (p[c.id] = c);  // if no d1 or d1 < d2 insert at index position designated by the id
                                 return p;},[]);
console.log(reduced);
var s = new Set(reduced); // now only one undefined left
s.delete(undefined); // get rid of that one too and use as a set or
reduced = [...s]; //get back your now properly reduced array.
console.log(reduced);
```

In case of a sparse array like above, you will have undefined values at those indices with no ids exist. Then you can simply get rid of them by doing like

```
var s = new Set(reduced); // now only one undefined left
s.delete(undefined); // get rid of that one too and use as a set or
reduced = [...s]; //get back your now properly reduced array.
```